# Drag and Drop in Angular 13

Tags: angular-material, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I want to drag an element from one component (e.g. a material list) to a material tree. Actually I found no sample how to do this. What I found is a drag and drop sample, that uses two lists (https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-disabled-sorting-example.html). Drag and drop inside a material-tree is not a problem. But how can I drag an element from a material list into a material tree and insert a new node at the selected location in the tree (in Angular 13)?